# Keeping row content bound in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have three main sheets in my spreadsheet. The first is a collection if items with relevant details for them, the second is a list of people. The third is used to set some basic relations between the two.

Here are some short examples of the three sheets:

#### Sheet 1

| Name | Description | Reactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item #1 | This is an example | Loved: Bob. Liked: Charlie |
| Item #2 | Another example | Liked: Alice, Charlie |

The third column here is data from sheet 3.

#### Sheet 2

- Alice
- Bob
- Charlie
- David

(The formatting of the table for sheet 2 only works in the preview for some reason, it's just a list of names starting on the first row.

#### Sheet 3

|  | Alice | Bob | Charlie | David |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item #1 |  | Loved | Liked |  |
| Item #2 | Liked |  | Liked |  |

Because sheet 3 is using data from the first two sheets, it looks like this behind the scenes:

|  | `=TRANSPOSE('Sheet 2'!A1:A)` |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `=ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet 1'!A2:A)` |  | Loved | Liked |  |
|  | Liked |  | Liked |  |

My problem is that both sheet 1 and sheet 2 are alphabetised which changes the order of things for sheet 3 if a new item or person is added. The reactions in the third sheet *need* to match up with both the item and person no matter what.

I unfortunately learnt all this the hard way when I added new items and people and I wasn't prepared for all the data being shifted around.

Is there anyway I can keep the data in sheet 3 bound to the respective items/people? Before anyone suggests it, no, I will not be removing the alphabetisation of sheets 1 and 2.

I've created an example spreadsheet for all of this. Feel free to make a copy to play around with this as I'd love to be able to actually *see* a working result.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T1ysSe11vZaS8AkASAA5EczHarniRCLjDnycMrCXBLc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See [row misalignment](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).

Comment: @doubleunary I can see how that might help if sheet 3 was only pulling in data from either sheet 1 or sheet 2, but it's pulling from both, both are dynamic. This method also relies on filtering out blank rows, but what about column for my other sheet? I don't think this will work for me. If I'm wrong, please submit an actual answer explaining it.

Answer (score -1):

The formulas you show for `Sheet3` only fill the first row and the first column, so I am assuming that you are manually inputing data in the range `Sheet3!B2:D`. If that is the case, you are exposed to the risk of [row misalignment](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649), and may have to rethink your spreadsheet structure.

One way to do that would be to reverse the dependency: insert a column for "Description" in `Sheet3`, manually enter items, descriptions, names and reactions in `Sheet3`, and use formulas to derive all of `Sheet1` from the data in `Sheet3`. You will then no longer need `Sheet2`.

`Sheet1` looks like a report that would usually be totally formula generated, but if you want to be able to enter a selection of names in column `A` there, you can use a `filter()` formula in cell `B2` there to only show the descriptions and reactions relevant to the names you have entered. The row misalignment problem is not with `Sheet1` but with `Sheet3`, and there is no easy turn-key solution to it.

Comment: Both `TRANSPOSE` and `ARRAYFORMULA` most definitely pull in all the rows/columns. The only thing manually entered on Sheet 3 is the loved/liked reactions. I need sheet 2 because it keeps a list of people, which is also dynamic. It sounds like what you're saying is to only use sheet 1 for the names and then have everything in sheet 3 which defeats the purpose of sheet 1 to begin with... All of this is a hard no. It doesn't solve my problem in the slightest. You're just making everything more difficult.

Comment: The `transpose()` formula you show fills one row, and the `arrayformula()` you show fills one column. Please confirm whether range `Sheet3!B2:D` contains manually entered data or formula generated data.

Comment: I misunderstood your initial statement, your comment is much clearer. Yes, `Sheet3!B2:D` is all manually entered. I've edited my main question with a link to an example spreadsheet that contains all the formulas I use in my actual sheet.